# Compare two integers for similarity 

Tags: python, comparison, similarity

Example:

```
number1 = 54378
number2 = 54379
if number1 (is similar to) number2:
   print (number1 + " " + number2)
   input("what to do")
```

I would like to compare between these two numbers, and let the program notify me when this kind of (between number1 and number2 ) similarity happens.

I would like the solution to be flexible with some room for more similarities (_ust the first digit is different).

BTW, I am using Python 3.X

Comment: You haven't defined similarity.

Comment: define similar to. Is there a range?

Comment: Similar to each other, isn't 100% similar but some do. I have added more explenation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`difflib`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) for this:

```
>>> from difflib import SequenceMatcher
>>> number1 = 54378
>>> number2 = 54379
>>> SequenceMatcher(None, str(number1), str(number2)).ratio()
0.80000000000000004
```

After creating a `SequenceMatcher` object with string representations of their numbers, use [`ratio()`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.ratio) (or `quick_ratio()` or `real_quick_ratio()` if speed is an issue) to get a similarity rating between 0 and 1.

After playing around with it a bit you can figure out what a good metric is for how similar they should be, and use it like this:

```
metric = 0.6   # just an example value
if SequenceMatcher(None, str(a), str(b)).ratio() > metric:
    # a and b are similar
```

Comment: this looks like comparing base10 representation of the two numbers, not the numbers themselves...

Answer (score 0):

you could do one of the following:
Both will take in uneven numbers such as `(100, 10)` `(200, 12)`

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def findSim(a, b):
    aS = str(a)
    bS = str(b)

    return [abs(int(x)-int(y)) if y != None else int(x) for x,y in izip_longest(aS,bS)]
```

returns a list with all the positional differences,

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def findSim(a, b):
    aS = str(a)
    bS = str(b)

    return sum(abs(int(x)-int(y)) if y != None else int(x) for x,y in izip_longest(aS,bS))
```

returns the sum difference of all positions.